# Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView on application launch

Tags: android, android-layout

After updating to Android Support Library version 22.2 no longer run all the projects, even empty projects. I work in Eclipse with the ADT plugin.

Examples of code.

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

After starting the application I get the following error in LogCat:

```
06-06 22:17:15.911: D/AndroidRuntime(13239): Shutting down VM
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239): Process: com.example.test, PID: 13239
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:117)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:757)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:890)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:656)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(Unknown Source)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:656)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Unknown Source)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    ... 11 more
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.test-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:571)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    ... 30 more
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):        ... 33 more
06-06 22:17:15.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13239):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Try to rebuild the project. Also what theme does your activity use?

Comment: @Simas , I rebuilt the project, but it has not given a positive result. I use the theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Comment: Your question's title shows a different error than the ones posted in your logcat. Could you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Simas , OK, question has been edited.

Comment: Also post your app's `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Simas I don't have it, because my projects in Eclipse don't use Gradle. Eclipse builds their own.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. What I did was I remove the `appcompat-v7` and re-add it again to the workspace and it should be renamed into `android-support-v7-appcompat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this this to dependencies

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

if its not working add jar library to your lib folder and rebuild your project then remove jar library and run your project.

jar files are in this folder path

> C:\Users\Lakshan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\support

Go to design and v7 folders and copy both jar files to your project.

if you cant find jar files in this path update your extras in sdk.Specially Android support libraries.